# Suggested tag synonym: gnupg/gpg

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

The tags [gnupg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnupg) and [gpg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gpg) seem to be synonyms, its [Wikipedia page also says that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard):

> GNU Privacy Guard (GnuPG or GPG) is a [...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest we make [gnupg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnupg) the canonical tag, i.e.:

[gpg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gpg) → [gnupg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnupg).

While the shorter tag is used more often on SU (likely because of the command name?), the authors use the longer variant on their own website, and the domain is `gnupg.org`.

> [image: GnuPG logo]

Comment: agree, this is done.